# Simulation and visualization of traces and signal on a map

Tags: java, dictionary, visualization, signal-strength

Concept: A database contains the signal strength values of several access points in a building. The values have been collected after a walk through the corridors of the building. Now I want to visualize this route on a floor map with the changes of the signal strength.

So I need to implement a visualization/simulation mechanism in Java for this. What do you suggest? From where should I start? Any help? I am not looking for something professional..

[example](http://www.flukenetworks.com/sites/flukenetworks.com/files/assets/image2_0.png)

Comment: @AdamArold the first result is my question!

Comment: Then you should skip it.

Comment: @AdamArold thanks but I prefer to skip your useless advice.

Comment: Take a look at this discussion How To Draw Simple 3D Point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313917/how-to-draw-simple-3d-pointsx-y-z-in-java-using-java3d-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place to start is really simple: create a 2D canvas, and at each x,y where signal was measured, put a colored circle that indicates signal strength. This will allow you to distinguish a dozen levels of strength. If you need more info you can then put a mouse event handler so if you hover over a circle you can get strength value. After that, you'll probably realize other capabilities you need and this will guide your next set of features. This will lead to organic growth of your app, which will eventually make it unmaintainable. ;)  At that point you will have gained significant understanding of your requirements (visualization, edit, etc), so you'll be able to start fresh with a clear set of requirements, a more robust design, and the added features that were too difficult to implement before the re-design :)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking if I need to deal with heat maps and this kind of stuff. That's why I asked what's the best way to start.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you didn't mention heat maps, you might have received more answers. But also, you should search around and state some alternatives you consider.

Comment: As I said I was not sure and that's why I asked. However thank you for your help!